# debian: add custom patch to dkms module

Tags: debian, dkms

I have a kernel driver that fails to compile, I have a patch to fix it but every time I run `dkms build ...` the driver sources (in `/usr/src`) are restored, is there a way to add a custom patch to a dkms driver?

Answer (score 1):

It was simpler and took less time than I anticipated, as `man 8 dkms` says just put them in`/usr/src/<module>-<module-version>/patches/`and then add the file name of the patch in`dkms.conf` of the module with `PATCH[#]=`

I wonder what will happen when the module is updated.

Comment: put it on hold (apt-mark hold ...) , at least you'll know when to check.

Comment: @A.B Thanks for the suggestion, it's the nvidia driver, if something goes wrong I should notice (Xorg won't work). I imagine that for a major change there will be a new directory (so no custom patch), while for a minor change `dkms.conf` could be overwritten, maybe the `patches/` directory will be deleted, nothing serious :-)

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer should work, I was unable to get it to work. Instead I used `PRE_BUILD=patch.sh` in `dkms.conf` to invoke `patch -p1 /path/to/mypatch.sh`